# Lorentz transformation equations: an insight

Tags: special-relativity, spacetime, speed-of-light, inertial-frames

Let Bob be moving towards the positive $x$-axis and Alice be stationary at the origin. Then the Lorentz transformation gives:

$$t' = \gamma\left( t- \frac{v x}{c^2}\right)$$

where $t'$ is the time of Bob,  $t$ is the time of  Alice. If time of Alice is held constant, and $x'$ represents the spatial coordinate of Bob, this will hold true:

$\dfrac{\partial t'}{\partial x'} \Bigg|_t  $ $\neq$ 0.

In this way, I am actually trying to express the fact that "all the clocks of Bob are not synchronised according to Alice" mathematically.

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/479421) to type formulae. I tried to adapt your post to it, but the meaning of the last equation is not clear (I'm not sure whether you meant $|_t$ or something else). Please edit it to MathJax so other users can understand the question better.

Comment: Contrary to the title, this does not appear to be an insight, but rather a muddle.

Comment: "If time of Alice is held constant" , is it possible to develop this assertion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Then the Lorentz transformation gives:

> $$t' = \gamma\left( t- \frac{v x}{c^2}\right)$$

> where $t'$ is the time of Bob,  $t$ is the time of  Alice. If time of Alice is held constant, and $x'$ represents the spatial coordinate of Bob, will this hold true:

> $\dfrac{\partial t'}{\partial x'} \Bigg|_t = 0 $?

Your question is not totally clear to me. I will try to answer the question that I think you are asking. Long story short, the answer is no. Details below.

The only way I can make sense of your question is when the expression for t' is re-written to eliminate x (such that t' is now formally a function of x' and t). And in this case, you could ask whether or not the partial derivative of that function t'(x',t) with respect to x' is zero.

From the other Lorentz equation we have:
$$
x' = -\beta\gamma c t + \gamma x\;.
$$
Or, rearranging:
$$
x = \frac{1}{\gamma}\left(x' + v\gamma t\right)
$$

Plugging this in to eliminate x from your first equation gives:
$$
t' = \gamma\left( t - \frac{v}{\gamma c^2}\left(x' + v\gamma t\right)  \right)
$$
$$
=\gamma t - \frac{v}{c^2}x' - \frac{v^2}{c^2}\gamma t
$$
$$
=\gamma t\left(1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}\right) - \frac{v}{c^2}x' 
$$
$$
= \frac{t}{\gamma} - \frac{v}{c^2}x'
$$

So, we see that the partial derivative you are interested is not zero:
$$
\frac{\partial t'}{\partial x'} = -\frac{v}{c^2} \neq 0
$$

Comment: Could you please interpret your result physically. I thought that that partial derivation equation which I wrote should hold true because that equation represents that (1) "all clocks in Bob's frame must be synchronised with respect to Bob . "  But since that equation is wrong, how should we mathematically express (1)?

Comment: I don't have a physical interpretation of the result.

Comment: The physical interpretation is that a plane of constant time in S is a sloping slice through time in S', which is the basis of the relativity of simultaneity.

Comment: @GauravAnand As Marco Ocram said, the physical interpretation is that events at a constant $t$ are not simultaneous in the primed frame of reference. It simply shows that the clocks of Bob are not synchronized in Alice's frame.